# Set button color after animation on mouse enter

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have an animation on mouse hover for button to change background and text color, but I wish to set it after the click, and my code does not working.

```
 <Button Style="{StaticResource ButtonProduct}" x:Name="Overview_Button" Click="Overview_Button_Click" FontFamily="pack://application:,,,/Images/Fonts/#HandelGothicEF" Width="198" Height="50"   Margin="0,30,0,20" FontSize="26">
    <TextBlock FontFamily="Univers LT Std 57 Cn" FontSize="16" Text="Overview" />
</Button>
```

Generic XAML:

```
<!-- ButtonProduct -->
<Style x:Key="ButtonProduct" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Border Name="Border" CornerRadius="0" BorderThickness="0" Focusable="False" BorderBrush="Transparent" Background="White">
                    <ContentPresenter Margin="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" RecognizesAccessKey="True"/>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ColorAnimation From="White" To="#52b0ca" Duration="0:0:0.5" Storyboard.TargetName="Border" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeave">
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ColorAnimation From="#52b0ca" To="White" Duration="0:0:0.5" Storyboard.TargetName="Border" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Code:

```
private void Overview_Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var bc = new BrushConverter();
            Overview_Button.Background = (Brush)bc.ConvertFrom("#51b0ce");

            Clear_Main_Panel();
            overviewObj = new Overview(family, Product_CombBox.SelectedIndex);
            this.Center_Panel.Children.Add(overviewObj);
            isOverview = true;
        }
```

Comment: you can use <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Click"> for button.You haven't written code for click.

Comment: by "after the click" do you mean when mouse button is released? or held down?

Comment: Released. I can use  <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Click"> but I need to remove the color when other button clicked. And I only can achieved it via code

Comment: Sounds like you actually want a RadioButton then, and use the Checked event to set your color. When another button in the same RadioButton group is checked (i.e. clicked), the previously clicked button will then be Unchecked, and you can return it to it's original state.